# Javascript change border

Tags: javascript, html

I have some buttons in my page like:

```
<a id="1" onclick="javascript:randje(1);"></a>
<a id="2" onclick="javascript:randje(2);"></a>
```

Now i try to make a script that changes the border on the button where i click with:

```
function randje(A) {
    document.getElementById(A).style.borderColor = "green";
}
```

This works great. But i have a little list of this clickable links, sometimes 2, sometimes 5 or even more. And now i want to try to change the border of the button i click and set the border from the previous click back to black. Something like this, but this isnt working yet. Can anyone help me out?

```
function randje(A) {
    if ( B ) { document.getElementById(B).style.borderColor = "black" };
    document.getElementById(A).style.borderColor = "green";
    var B = A;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I havent got your goals, but: the scope `var B` is the function itself. Wont survive the return. Thus each time the condition in `if` will yield false. You could declare B in window scope. But you better work with classes: chosse a class name you like, and declare the border style. Then on click remove that class from all elements in the set, and add to the target of the event. If I understood correctly, there can be many B-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the declaration out of the function.

```js
var B;
function randje(A) {
    if(B){
      document.getElementById(B).style.borderColor  = "black"
    };
    document.getElementById(A).style.borderColor  = "green";
    B = A;
}
```

```css
a {border-style: dotted;}
```

```html
<a id="1" onclick="javascript:randje(1);">One</a>
<a id="2" onclick="javascript:randje(2);">Two</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an other option, supposing, that there are multiple links, as you wrote. The solution is jQuery based, but it can also be achieved in vanilla JavaScript.

```html
<style>
  a.link { border: 3px solid black; display: inline-block; padding: 1em;}
  a.link.selected { border-color: green; }
</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>   
<a class="link">1</a>
<a class="link">2</a>
<a class="link">3</a>
 
<script>
  $('a.link').on('click', (e) => {
    $('a.link').removeClass('selected');
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('selected');
  })
</script>
```